# Launch an Application on login for the Guest User

Tags: login-items, guest-account

I would like for the Guest Account on the iMacs in my school to automatically launch Google Chrome when the Guest Account is logged into.

With normal users, you can accomplish this with the Login Items tab of Users & Groups in System Preferences, but that tab is missing for the Guest User.

If I attempt to login to the Guest User and navigate to Login Items, I am able to add Chrome, but when I logout and log back in the login item is deleted.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really good answer for this question:

> The easiest way would be the following:
>
> 1. Download, install and update the [free Server Admin Tool](http://free%20Server%20Admin%20Tools)s from Apple.
> 2. If you´re currently logged into the Guest User Account, log out.
>      Open /Applications/Server/Workgroup Manager and connect to Address:
>      localhost with the username and password of your admin user
> 3. Ignore the warning message about working on a local configuration,
>      then go into the menu "View" and select "Show System Records".
> 4. On the left hand side, select the Guest-User and in the window
>      titlebar click on "Preferences"
> 5. Click Dock on the right side. Select "Manage Always" at the top of
>      the window and then add and remove the Dock items you want in your
>      customized Dock. Uncheck the checkbox "Merge With User's Dock" at
>      the bottom of the window. Click on "Apply Now" and log in as the
>      Guest User to see it in effect.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/9537/258380

Comment: Sadly, that answer is outdated.  There are no Server Admin Tools for recent versions of OSX, and the most recent version of Workgroup Manager (10.9) will not install on High Sierra.  It requires 10.10 or earlier.